# Trying to figure out how to connect with PDO to MSSQL

Tags: php, sql-server

I am having an issue not sure how to get mssql connect to my slim framework with angular js. I have it working with mysql.

part of my helper code

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php'; // Database setting constants [DB_HOST, DB_NAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD]
class dbHelper {
    private $db;
    private $err;
    function __construct() {
        $dsn = 'mssql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME.';charset=utf8';
        try {
            $this->db = new PDO($dsn, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $response["status"] = "error";
            $response["message"] = 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
            $response["data"] = null;
            //echoResponse(200, $response);
            exit;
        }
    }
```

here is my config code

```
<?php
/**
 * Database configuration
 */
define('DB_USERNAME', 'puma');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'puma');
define('DB_HOST', 'WIN-F96PF4GQMCS\SQLEXPRESS');
define('DB_NAME', 'angularcode_products');

?>
```

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: no error just no connection the data is not showing up

Comment: not sure if slim will work with mssql

Comment: Please, can you uncomment this: `//echoResponse(200, $response);` and remove `exit`? I want to know what is the content of `$response`. If you're trying to get data using your code, you can't obtain it because you're only connecting to DB.

Comment: Slim does not know anything about databases. You are using PDO to connect to database. Check that your PHP installation does not have PDO MSSQL drivers installed.

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.drivers.php